# Bootcamp and SSD issue

Tags: bootcamp

I have loaded windows on the SSD of the macbook. I have plenty of windows softwares that i wish to install but that will be at the cost of the SSD which has a limited space. Is it ok to install the remaining softwares on the external HDD. Is this what the others guys are also doing???

Answer (score 1):

It will depend entirely on the software. Some programs run from anywhere, some must be on the boot volume.

Also note that you will probably get better answers on a Windows forum. You are running Windows on Mac hardware, which basically makes it a windows machine.